# Get only selected child category from the parent category

Tags: php, wordpress

first of i am no a developer i got of my friend ,i can get all the child category of category id "1292" with but its working fine, but i want to display only some of category i select from the category "1292"

```
<?php
$term_id = 1292;
$taxonomy_name = 'product_cat';
$term_children = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );
foreach ( $term_children as $child ) {
$term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
$category_thumbnail = get_woocommerce_term_meta($term->term_id,     'thumbnail_id', true);
$image = wp_get_attachment_url($category_thumbnail);
echo '<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12">

<div class="ado-prdct-cat">
    <div class="ado-prdct-cat-wrpr">
      <a href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name ) . '">  <img   src="'.$image.'">
    </div>

    <div class="ado-prdct-cat-ttl-wrpr">
    ' . $term->name . '</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>';
}
?>
```

category id 1292 has 15 child category and i want some of them to display on page by id from the parent id 1292, if any one know the best way for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does the selection happen, are you fine with hard coding the IDs to use / skip in your code?

You have the child's term id in $child, just add

```
if(in_array($child, array(123, 456))) continue;
```

before

```
$term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
```

to skip over the categories 123 and 456, or use `!in_array` to only show those and skip the others.
You can use a variable instead of `array(123, 456)`, of course.

Edit: turning this into a [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) is pretty easy as well:

```
add_shortcode( "mycategoryprinter" , function($attributes) {
    $skipids = array();
    if(array_key_exists("skipids", $attributes)) {
        $skipids = preg_split("/\s*,\s*/", $attributes["skipids"]);
    }
    $term_id = $attributes["termid];
    $taxonomy_name = $attributes["taxonomy];

    // code goes here, change echo to return

});
```

Which you can then use with something like

```
[mycategoryprinter termid="1292" taxonomy="product_cat" skipids="123, 456"][/mycategoryprinter]
```

Comment: can you please explain where to add the code or modify the code above posted by me because i got this code from google search

Comment: Replace `foreach ( $term_children as $child ) {` with `foreach ( $term_children as $child ) {
if(in_array($child, array(123, 456)) continue;`

Comment: i tried adding before it shows howing "syntax error unexpected T_CONTINUE"

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake. It was missing a closing parantheses on that line before `continue`, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but this work for me "  if(!in_array($child, array(1297, 1298))) continue;   " just added " ! " as i need thanks again thank you very much

Comment: See the updated answer. If you have trouble with implementing the shortcode, you should probably add another question.